# Blazor and routing pages

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app, it works perfectly when you go directly to it (for example `https://myBlazorapp:port`).  However, I need the app to be forward and part of a larger site.  So now it needs to be something like this: `https://mainsite:port/routeToMyBlazorapp`.

Pulling up the dev console for the webpage return this:

> bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
> a status of 404 (Not Found) default.css:1 Failed to load resource: the
> server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> ... and the rest of the resources of the Blazor app

I know the routing works due to the fact it is getting the error message in `_Host.cshtml`.  I have tried some changes to `<base href="~/" />` with no luck.

Not sure where to make the changes.

Comment: Try this: <base href="~/routeToMyBlazorapp" />

Comment: @enet this did not work and gives the same erros